# Build letter avatar grid by angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I create a simple letter avatar grid by ng-repeat but it i not work well. If I use search filter it only refresh the name. The icon is not refreshed by name.

Main html.

```
    <md-grid-tile ng-cloak ng-repeat="user in vm.users | filter: vm.searchText track by $index">
        <user-card name="{{user.name}}"></user-card>
    </md-grid-tile>
```

user-card directive:

```
        .directive("userCard", function () {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            template:
            "<md-card>" +
                "<md-card-title layout=\"column\" layout-align=\"center center\">"+
                    "<md-card-title-media layout=\"column\" layout-align=\"center center\">"+
                            "<md-button class=\"md-fab\" ng-style=\"{'background-color': color }\""+
                                "<span class=\"letter\">{{name[0]}}</span>"+
                            "</md-button>"+
                            "{{color}}"+
                        "<span>{{name}}</span>"+
                    "</md-card-title-media>"+
                "</md-card-title>"+
            "</md-card>",
            scope: {
                name: "@"
            },
           controller: function ($scope) {
                var alphabetColors = ["#5A8770", "#B2B7BB", "#6FA9AB", "#F5AF29", "#0088B9", "#F18636",
                    "#D93A37", "#A6B12E", "#5C9BBC", "#F5888D", "#9A89B5", "#407887", "#9A89B5",
                    "#5A8770", "#D33F33", "#A2B01F", "#F0B126", "#0087BF", "#F18636", "#0087BF",
                    "#B2B7BB", "#72ACAE", "#9C8AB4", "#5A8770", "#EEB424", "#407887"];
                var colorIndex = Math.floor(($scope.name.charCodeAt(0) - 65) % alphabetColors.length);
                $scope.color = alphabetColors[colorIndex];
            }
        }
    });
```

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/JXvhX8CoBELX3uqeUk1T)

I find that the question is I use

> track by $index

It is only refresh DOM object for user.name part not for all , that is why after search the color is not change by user. If I delete "track by $index" is work well, but it well has the performance issue when too many avatars( more then thousand ) on the page. **So the question is: it is a better way to make this on front-end?**

All the pagination, search, sort will happened on front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass in an obj to 'user-card' directive and save the color code to that object in the controller.

Updated plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/frLiLfMU7r0P4VCcfGC6

```
<md-grid-tile ng-cloak ng-repeat="user in vm.users | filter: vm.searchText track by $index">
   <user-card obj="user"></user-card>
</md-grid-tile>
```

Controller:

```
controller: function($scope) {
    var alphabetColors = ["#5A8770", "#B2B7BB", "#6FA9AB", "#F5AF29", "#0088B9", "#F18636",
              "#D93A37", "#A6B12E", "#5C9BBC", "#F5888D", "#9A89B5", "#407887", "#9A89B5",
              "#5A8770", "#D33F33", "#A2B01F", "#F0B126", "#0087BF", "#F18636", "#0087BF",
              "#B2B7BB", "#72ACAE", "#9C8AB4", "#5A8770", "#EEB424", "#407887"
            ];


    var colorIndex = Math.floor(($scope.obj.name.charCodeAt(0) - 65) % alphabetColors.length);
    $scope.obj.color = alphabetColors[colorIndex];
}
```